# How can I get console ssh to NOT ask for my private key password every time?

Tags: ssh, cryptography

I have a program required by work installed on a Debian Wheezy box. Previously I was using Mac OS X (switch details irrelevant). I have an SSH keypair at `~/.ssh/id_rsa{.pub}`. That keypair has a password on it.

The program I run for work uses executes a loop. That loop invokes SSH multiple times. Each trip through, I'm asked for my password for the private key again. On OS X, this happened only once per boot, regardless of uptime.

I want to get this to where I can input my ssh key password ONCE and have it accepted immediately every single time the key is invoked for the remainder of the machine's uptime (like how it's done on OS X).

I am NOT using a `gui`. No `xwin` here. This is a server installation.

Multiple searches have turned up only garbage introducing people to the concept of SSH keys. This is a bit more unique. Please point me at the right command so I can read the `man` page.

Comment: have you tried `ssh-agent` ? This is intended excatly for what you need.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you! For future searchers, here's how I got this working on Debian Wheezy:

echo "eval \`ssh-agent\`" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "ssh-add" >> ~/.bashrc

Logout, then log back in. On each login, it'll ask you for your password for the primary keys you have in ~/.ssh. The eval thing, while I dislike it, is useful because ssh-agent prints out (by default) the commands to set necessary environment variables for using ssh-add and ssh-agent in future commands.

Thanks again, Archemar. To l0b0, I don't think this is a duplicate because the solution seems quite different.

Comment: Bah how the hell do I mark this as answered by Archemar and give him credit that he most certainly deserves? I feel real friggin' smart today, folks...